# Not undestanding how to make a custom auth driver. Ultimately will need SOAP.

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.1

I am quite new to Laravel and I really need some help. I need to create a simple app for my job, and I think I will not have problem with this as the tutorials here are really excellent.

The issue I have is that for that project I need to authenticate the users against an external DB using a SOAP webservice and if the user does not exist in the local DB I create it and log the user in. I am able to manage this part as I have already written a Joomla plugin that does that.

I have tried to figure out the documentation on how to create a custom driver. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication I thought that at first I would replicate the EloquentUserProvider befor modifying it, thus I created:

`ErsAuthServiceProvider` and `ErsUserProvider` respectively placed in `App\Providers` and `App\Extensions`

But it mysteriously does not work... I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in ErsUserProvider.php line 33: Argument 1 passed to App\Extensions\ErsUserProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher, none given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/ERSTools/app/Providers/ErsAuthServiceProvider.php on line 31 and defined
```

Actually I do not understand much in the documentation what they are doing with the `boot()` method in the example. I understand that they extend The `Auth` class in order to add the new driver (ers in my case) but I do not get why they pass the `$app['riak.connection']`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Auth;
use App\Extensions\ErsUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate as GateContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

    class ErsAuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

    {

        protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];


    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        parent::registerPolicies($gate);

         Auth::extend('ers', function($app) {
            // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...
            return new ErsUserProvider;
        });

        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

and

```
<?php

namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher as HasherContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

class ErsUserProvider implements UserProvider
{
   /**
     * The hasher implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher
     */
    protected $hasher;

    /**
     * The Eloquent user model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model;

    /**
     * Create a new database user provider.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Hashing\Hasher  $hasher
     * @param  string  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(HasherContract $hasher, $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }
... the rest is similar to the original file (EloquentUserProvider)
```

Finally, my plan is to keep the `ErsUserprovider` quite similar to the `EloquentUserProvider` and to implement my check with the webservice in the `validateCredentials()` method as in this method I shoul know if a user exists with the requested username in the local DB, I will know if the user passes validation with the SOAP webservice I can then

1. Login the user
2. Login the user and create a new user based on the date returned by the webservice
3. refuse the login.

Is this a good plan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sweated but I made the first part work. The issue was within the boot method.My custom provider is a working replica of the original laravel 5.1 I can now customize it.

Here is the Service provider that works:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Extensions\ErsUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class ErsAuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{
 /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {

        $this->app['auth']->extend('ers',function($app)
        {
            $model = $app['config']['auth.model'];
            return new ErsUserProvider($app['hash'], $model);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```